# ng-select with better rendering on mobile device

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I use the ng-select angular library https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select with angular7. Is it possible to open the native list on mobile device as a real select tag ? For example :

```
<select id="cars" name="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="fiat">Fiat</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Thanks,

Comment: So you don't want ng-select styles and functionality in mobile devices right?

Comment: actually yes :) maybe I have to code something else for mobile device finally... Well, is there a way to be sure that my visitor is on a mobile device ?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply **ng-select** only if you have target device as desktop. For mobile devices just show native select. Try below function to detect mobile device.

```js
 function getDevice() {
         var ua = navigator.userAgent;
         return (ua.indexOf('iPhone') != -1) ? 'iphone' : ((ua.indexOf('iPad') != -1) ? 'ipad' :       ((ua.indexOf('Android') != -1) ? 'android' : 'desktop'));
}

console.log('You are using', getDevice())
```